# WhenEvent and partial derivatives

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

Can `WhenEvent` be used to reset the conditions on a PDE at a given time?
How would the syntax of that be?

This is the code I`m using

```
r = 2;
d2 = 1;
l = 5;
sol = NDSolve[{Derivative[0, 1][n][x, t] ==
               d2 Derivative[2, 0][n][x, t] + r*n[x, t]*(1 - n[x, t]),
               n[x, 0] == 0.1*x*(1 - x/l), n[0, t] == 0, n[l, t] == 0,
               WhenEvent[t == 50, n[x, t] -> 0]}, {n}, {x, 0, l}, {t, 0, tmax}]
```

Comment: Could you maybe specify the particular PDE you're working with, so that it's easier for us to show you how?

Comment: Im trying to solve a reaction diffusion equation with NDSolve, and reset the density function mid integration

Comment: sol = NDSolve[{
   \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]\(n[x, t]\)\) == d2*\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(x, x\)]\(n[x, t]\)\) + 
     r*n[x, t]*(1 -  n[x, t]), 
   n[x, 0] == 0.1*x*(1 - x/l), n[0, t] == 0, n[l, t] == 0,
   WhenEvent[t == 50, n[x, t] -> 0]}, {n}, {x, 0, l}, {t, 0, tmax},

Comment: that's the code im trying

Comment: Well, please edit that code into your post, instead of posting that in comments...

Comment: Thanks and sorry for that, First time user here!

Comment: No problem, but without some typical values for the parameters (`l`, `d2`, etc.), it's hard to test.  Could you add those to the question?

Comment: Typical parameters added!

Answer (score 17):

According to the error message:

> `NDSolve::nlnum1: "The function value {0} is not a list of numbers with dimensions {25} when the arguments are {50.,{<<25>>}."`

I think you should feed a 25-length list of `0` to `n[x,t]` in the `WhenEvent`:

```
WhenEvent[t > 50, n[x, t] -> ConstantArray[0, 25]]
```

Plot the result:

```
Plot3D[Evaluate[n[x, t] /. sol], {x, 0, l}, {t, 0, 100}, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]

**Edit:**

According to the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NDSolve.html), *`NDSolve` automatically does processing for discontinuous functions like `Sign`*, so here an alternative way which do not require manual specifying the number of grid nodes (*i.e.* 25):

```
sol2 = NDSolve[{
   Derivative[0, 1][n][x, t] ==
             d2*Derivative[2, 0][n][x, t] + 
             r*Sign[50 - t]*n[x, t]*(1 - Sign[50 - t]*n[x, t]),
    n[x, 0] == 0.1*x*(1 - x/l),
    n[0, t] == 0, 
       n[l, t] == 0},
   {n}, {x, 0, l}, {t, 0, 100}]
```

Note the difference near the discontinuity line between this solution and `sol` by above `WhenEvent`:

```
Show[
 MapThread[Plot3D[
    Evaluate[n[x, t] /. #1], {x, 0, l}, {t, 49, 53},
    PlotPoints -> 50, PlotStyle -> None,
    MeshFunctions -> (#1 &), MeshStyle -> #2,
    BoundaryStyle -> None, PlotRange -> All
    ] &,
  {{sol, sol2}, {Red, Blue}}
  ]]
```

[image]

**Edit 2:**

Using `WhenEvent` with automatic detecting the x-grid:

```
<< DifferentialEquations`InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy`
Clear[xGridExtractor]
xGridExtractor[f_] := InterpolatingFunctionCoordinates[Head[f]][[1]]

sol = NDSolve[
        {
         Derivative[0, 1][n][x, t] == d2*Derivative[2, 0][n][x, t] + r*n[x, t]*(1-n[x, t]), 
         n[x, 0] == 0.1*x*(1 - x/l),
         n[0, t] == 0,
         n[l, t] == 0, 
         WhenEvent[t > 50, n[x, t] -> 0*xGridExtractor[n[x, t]]]
        },
        {n}, {x, 0, l}, {t, 0, 100}]
```

**Edit 3:**

According to OP's comment, here is how to reset the initial condition along $t=50$ in a more general sense:

```
sol = NDSolve[
        {
         Derivative[0, 1][n][x, t] == d2*Derivative[2, 0][n][x, t] + r*n[x, t]*(1-n[x, t]), 
         n[x, 0] == 0.1*x*(1 - x/l),
         n[0, t] == 0,
         n[l, t] == 0, 
         WhenEvent[t > 50, n[x, t] -> (.5 Head[n[x, t]] /@ xGridExtractor[n[x, t]])]
        },
        {n}, {x, 0, l}, {t, 0, 100}]

Plot3D[Evaluate[n[x, t] /. sol], {x, 0, l}, {t, 49, 51},
     PlotPoints -> 50, MeshFunctions -> {#2 &, #3 &}, Exclusions -> t == 50]
```

[image: half value]

Comment: +1. I was just writing such an answer!  The array seems to reinitialize the values of `n[x, 50]` along the line `0 <= x <= l` -- probably the interpolation grid.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks and agree. I think there should be an alternative way which does not require manual specifying the number of grid nodes.

Comment: I like the use of `Sign[]`, but maybe the PDE will look nicer if you use `Piecewise[]`.

Comment: @0x4A4D I just tried `Piecewise`, and I think I'd prefer the `WhenEvent` version. Neither `Sign` nor `Piecewise` are as good as `WhenEvent` near the discontinuity interface.

Comment: That's too bad. I was hoping for an alternative that'd also work in earlier versions of *Mathematica*. (I'm still on version 8.)

Comment: @0x4A4D In that case I guess we'd have to increase the interpolation points on x-grid..

Comment: @MichaelE2 I've spent some time trying to adapt your solutions for a case in which the density is halfed instead of zeroed. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Just for my curiosity, how did you manage to @ more than one person?

Comment: @MichaelE2, sorry for mistagging!

Comment: @Silvia I think he can do that because im the thread owner, so im automatically notified

Comment: @fernando Thanks to inform :) Do you mean you want `n[x, t] -> 0.5 n[x, t]`?

Comment: @Silvia, yes, that's what I'm trying now! By the way, I feel like I owe you a cupcake or something for all the help, thanks a lot!

Comment: @fernando You are welcome :) Please see my **edit 3**.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks for informing. I thought there are some tricks :D