# How to modify a PDE inside NDSolve according to an if condition

Tags: numerical-integration, version-9, differential-equations

I need to solve this PDE
$$\partial_tf(t,x)+\partial_xf(t,x)+k\partial_{xx}f(t,x)-xf(t,x)=0 $$

with $k\in\mathbb{R}$ and final condition $f(T,x)=1$ with $0<t<T$.

My problem is how to solve numerically this PDE according to this:

$\begin{cases} k=k_1, \quad \partial_{xx}f(t,x) \ge 0 \\k=k_2, \quad \partial_{xx}f(t,x)<0 \end{cases}$

with $k_1,k_2\in\mathbb{R}$.

I supposed `WhenEvent` were to be used, therefore I set

```
T = 1
pde = D[f[t, T, x], {t, 1}] + D[f[t, T, x], {x, 1}] + k*D[f[t, T, x], {x, 2}] - 
x*f[t, T, x] == 0
cond = f[T, T, x] == 0
```

and with `NDSolve`

```
sol = NDSolve[{pde, cond, 
WhenEvent[D[f[t, T, x], {x, 2}] >= 0, k -> 0.1], 
WhenEvent[D[f[t, T, x], {x, 2}] < 0, k -> 0.05]}, 
f[t, T, x], {t, 0, T}, {x, 0, 0.5}]
```

but i got this error

*NDSolve::ivone: Boundary values may only be specified for one independent variable. Initial values may only be specified at one value of the other independent variable.*

**ADDED**: I pointed out that $f$ is a function only in $t$ and $x$, `T` is inserted in the code because it tries to replicate a *bond-finance* setting. Moreover, removing from the code the `WhenEvent` part I got a solution similar to this one: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/78186/pde-solved-with-ndsolve-how-can-i-plot-the-partial-derivatives-of-the-solution

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Is the function `f[t, y, x]` or `f[t, x]` or `f[y, x]`? And you still miss 2 boundary conditions. (A rule of thumb for the necessary number of i.c. or b.c. is that it should be usually equal to the highest order of the corresponding derivative.)

Comment: @xyzcd Your point is right, I mixed two different ways to formulate my problem. I've fixed the question. Thank you

Comment: Well, I still suggest you to add the missing b.c.s, though `NDSolve` gives an answer currently, it's not that clear [what boundary is added](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/73961/1871).

Comment: Yes, I have another bc, it is $\lim_{x \to +\infty}f(x,t)=0$, but I don't know how to add it. I tried with high values of x but I got errors. Moreover, in finance the standard condition used is the only one I wrote in the question. If can be useful, here there is a video that speaks about it: it's quite long, the part about this point is at 24:41 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sDmjVCx8Edw

Comment: I tried with an ODE case, modifying the initial problem (but still inserting the "if" case on the highest order derivative) and adding the right number of conditions: in that case, I got an error too. So my point is: suppose the problem is correctly specified, how can i implement this kind of "if"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my opinion, `WhenEvent` is still a wild beast in *Mathematica*, actually the only example for handling PDE with `WhenEvent` in the document only sets a `"StopIntegration"` event. Indeed, `WhenEvent` is able to do more, but quite tricky, see [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26699/1871) for example.

For your problem, I think using `Piecewise` is a possible solution:

```
T = 1;
pde = D[f[t, x], {t, 1}] + D[f[t, x], {x, 1}] + 
      Piecewise[{{0.1, D[f[t, x], {x, 2}] >= 0}}, 0.05] D[f[t, x], {x, 2}] - 
      x f[t, x] == 0;
cond = {f[T, x] == 0, f[t, 10] == 0, Derivative[0, 1][f][t, 10] == 0};

sol = NDSolveValue[{pde, cond}, f[t, x], {t, 0, T}, {x, 0, 10}]

Plot3D[sol, {t, 0, T}, {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Notice I used `f[t, 10] == 0` and `Derivative[0, 1][f][t, 10] == 0` to approximate the b.c.s. (Not sure if it's proper. ) The resulting plot isn't that interesting under the parameters you gave, so I'd like to omit it here. (More difficult parameters seem to lead to other problems though. )

Comment: +1. I agree `Piecewise` seems the way to go. I think the "when" in `WhenEvent` suggests it reacts to events in time, and actions that change a variable have to reinitialize the variable at each point in the spatial grid.  That means you might have to know what the spatial grid actually is.  (This remark pertains to the method of lines; I haven't looked into `WhenEvent` with FEM.)

Comment: without selecting proper coefficient is not so interesting but i changed them and it solves exactly what i was searching for. in fact, i was trying to solve a princing pde for a bond for example, so t mean time, and x the interest rate (so the plotting solution should be for $0<x<0.50$) while the piecewise condition for the volatility: changing it according to the concavity means uncertain volatility and the model is normally called UMV (developed by Avellaneda, Levy, Paras in 1995). thank you very much for your help