# WhenEvent and Resetting of Variable in PDE when operation succeeds

Tags: differential-equations

I have had success in using `WhenEvent` to reset or change a variable within `NDSolve` with ordinary differential equations.  My **working, functioning** MWE is:

```
Clear[usol, u, t, x, λ];
usol = NDSolveValue[
  {
   D[u[t, x], t] == λ[t, x] D[u[t, x], x, x],
   u[0, x] == 0,
   u[t, 0] == Sin[t],
   u[t, 5] == 0,
   λ[0, x] == 1,
   WhenEvent[t > 5, λ[t, x] -> 1.25*λ[t, x]]
   },
  u,
  {t, 0, 10},
  {x, 0, 5},
  DiscreteVariables -> λ]
Plot3D[usol[t, x], {t, 0, 10}, {x, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> All]
NIntegrate[usol[1, x], {x, 0, 5}]) (*This evaluates to 0.669665*)
```

However, I would like to use `WhenEvent` to perform an operation such as `StopIntegration` or changing a variable when a calculation such as *area under the curve* represented by the dependent variable attains a certain value.  For this, I tried:

```
Clear[usol, u, t, x, λ];
usol = NDSolveValue[
  {
   D[u[t, x], t] == λ[t, x] D[u[t, x], x, x],
   u[0, x] == 0,
   u[t, 0] == Sin[t],
   u[t, 5] == 0,
   λ[0, x] == 1,
   WhenEvent[NIntegrate[usol[t, x], {x, 0, 5}] > 0.1, end = t; 
    "StopIntegration"]
   },
  u,
  {t, 0, 10},
  {x, 0, 5},
  DiscreteVariables -> λ]
```

However, I am beset with a slew of error messages in this latter case.  The error message starts with:

> The integrand usol[0,x] has evaluated to non-numerical values for all
>   sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,5}}

The other question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/26697/204) on `WhenEvent`  and `NDSolve` for partial differential equations did not have similar errors.

I am not sure what is going wrong; the operation `NIntegrate[usol[t, x], {x, 0, 5}] < 1` should have "ended" the NDSolve Integration at t=1 at the least as in my functioning MWE.

Comment: You can't use `usol` until `NDSolveValue` ends. So, you certainly can't use it **inside** `NDSolveValue`

Comment: @Dr.belisarius So, how do I proceed? I am sorry but I do not have a clue. What you say makes sense.

Comment: Probably include an auxiliary function whose derivative is `u` and include that equation inside `NDSolve`. I'm not sure exactly how this would work. I might think on it.

Comment: I think if you just change `usol` to `u` inside `NIntegrate`, it should work.

Comment: @march Indeed! Wow! Was that an easy fix or what...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in a comment